# Unrecognized option '--useSqlite'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to create a Scaffolding (MVC Controller with Views and EF) and when bulding, it shows this error:

```
    Building project...
Running /Users/gvpomac/Projects/CSharp/SalesWebMvc/SalesWebMvc/obj/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --project "/Users/gvpomac/Projects/CSharp/SalesWebMvc/SalesWebMvc/SalesWebMvc.csproj" controller --model Department --dataContext IdentityDbContext  --referenceScriptLibraries   -name DepartmentsController --no-build -outDir "/Users/gvpomac/Projects/CSharp/SalesWebMvc/SalesWebMvc/Controllers" --controllerNamespace SalesWebMvc.Controllers --useSqlite 
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.
Unrecognized option '--useSqlite'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.HandleUnexpectedArg(CommandLineApplication command, String[] args, Int32 index, String argTypeName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:05.81
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have missed something in your startup config. Check the documentation.

Comment: When I do the same type of project (.NET Core MVC) using 3.0 it works pretty well, but when Im using .NET Core 2.0 it happens.

Comment: It seems you forget to install  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`  in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i change **--useSqlite** to **-sqlite**. 
It worked for me without problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use terminal to pass this problem. it seems such as the bug with packages.

> and also yeah sth between **--useSqlite & -sqlite** flags.

Windows:`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries -sqlite`

non-windows:`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages/Movies --referenceScriptLibraries -sqlite`